# Phonegap: iOS error after CLI upgrade to 6.5.0

Tags: phonegap

I upgraded a working Phonegap App from CLI version 6.1.0 to 6.5.0 according to new guidelines of Adobe build cloud service as of December 1st 2018.
Since I upgraded to CLI Version 6.5.0, I am experiencing a new bug with the iOS Version of my app. Right after app start, the activity animation remains visible instead of loading the login page of the app. With version 6.1.0 the user would be exposed to the location permission pop up window, which is not showing up with CLI 6.5.0. Instead, upon clicking the home button on the iPhone, I get to see the permission pop up outside the app. Irrespective of what I choose inside the pop-up, when returning to the app, the login screen will then be fully loaded.
This is my current config.xml. I basically just changed the phone gap-version entry from „cli-6.1.0“ to „cli-6.5.0“.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
        xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id=„foo“ 
        version=„1.1“ versionCode="90">

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString"> 
        <string>1.1</string>
    </gap:config-file>

    <name>foo</name>

    <description>
        foo
    </description>

    <author email=„foo“ href=„foo“>
        foo
    </author>

    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />

    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>

    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application">
        <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" />
    </gap:config-file>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIBackgroundModes" overwrite="true">
        <array>
            <string>location</string>
        </array>
    </gap:config-file>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" overwrite="true">
        <array>
            <string>comgooglemaps</string>
            <string>tomtomhome</string>
            <string>navigon</string>
        </array>
    </gap:config-file>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"> 
        <string>foo</string> 
    </gap:config-file>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"> 
        <string>foo</string> 
    </gap:config-file>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSMotionUsageDescription"> 
        <string>foo</string> 
    </gap:config-file> 

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">  
      <string>foo</string> 
    </gap:config-file> 

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icons/android/ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icons/android/mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icons/android/hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icons/android/xhdpi.png" />

    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />

    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="1024" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon_57_57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon_58_58.png" width="58" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="87" src="res/icons/ios/icon_87_87.png" width="87" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon_at_2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="res/splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="res/splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="res/splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="res/splash/android/xhdpi.png" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <platform name="ios">
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default.png" width="320" height="480" />
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png" width="640" height="1136" />
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default_iphone6.png" width="750" height="1334" />
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default_iphone6_at3x.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
    </platform>

    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/splash/ios/Default.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/splash/ios/Default_iphone6.png" width="750" height="1334" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/splash/ios/Default_iphone6_at3x.png" width="1242" height="2208" /> 

    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />

    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.2.0" />

    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.1" />
    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.1" />

    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="3.0.0" />
    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.3.0" />
    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.0.1" />

    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="2.1.0" />
    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.1.1" />
    <plugin source="npm" name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.1.0" />

    <plugin name="https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability.git#v0.3.1" />
    <plugin name="https://github.com/interFace-dk/phonegap-googlenavigate.git" />
    <plugin name="https://github.com/kdileep1990/com.dileep.plugins.datepicker.git#0.0.1" />
    <plugin name="https://github.com/cmackay/google-analytics-plugin.git#v1.0.2" />

    <preference name="cordova-background-geolocation-license" value=„123“ />
    <plugin name="background-geolocation" spec="1.7.3" source="pgb" />
      <plugin name="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-app-event.git#1.2.0" />
      <plugin name="https://github.com/cliqueApp/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git#master" />

    <plugin source="npm" name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.7.2">
        <param name="SENDER_ID" value=„123“ />
    </plugin>

</widget>
```

I suspect, there is something wrong with the way I am calling the NSLocation with the new CLI Version. 
Any other vital changes arising from the version change to 6.5.0? Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2410644). Long story short, this is how I solved this issue: 
- config.xml (changed the version number, I used an older one):

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.3" />
```

- index.html (added this line):

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src * gap://ready; default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* *; connect-src * blob: data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src data: *" />
```

have fun.